# How the ZeroDivisionError process

Tags: python, ns-3

I would like to know what is the use of ZeroDivisionError and how it works in the following example code?

```
try:
   hopCounts.append(flow_stats.timesForwarded/ flow_stats.rxPackets)
except ZeroDivisionError:            
    flow_stats.jitterSum.GetSeconds() == 0
```

Comment: Who wrote this code? If you have a zero-division error, you already know RxPackets() should be 0... Also, why are you discarding the result of the check. Basically, this code attempts a numerical operation, catches division by zero errors, and then writes a useful statement rather than use `pass` or anything else. I'm not entirely sure what's going on either...

Comment: This code catches zero division error that will occur if `flow_stats.rxPackets` is equal to zero. Though I am not sure why one need the boolean comparison which is not assigned to anything in exception handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the code-sample you gave:

```
try:
    # try block
    hopCounts.append(flow_stats.timesForwarded / flow_stats.rxPackets)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    # exception block
    flow_stats.jitterSum.GetSeconds() == 0
```

The *try block* will run the code inside the brackets first `flow_stats.timesForwarded / flow_stats.rxPackets`.
If `flow_stats.rxPackets` is zero, then the `ZeroDivisionError` exception will be raised.
Otherwise, the value calculated will be appended to the `hopCounts` list.
The *exception block* will not be executed.

If the `ZeroDivisionError` exception was raised, that exception will be caught by the `except` statement, and the *exception block* code will run
`flow_stats.jitterSum.GetSeconds() == 0`

However, that code won't do anything, it will simply return `True` or `False`... it has the same effect as simply writing `True` in python on a line by itself.

To learn more, read http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/error-handling/exception-handling-in-python

Comment: When the I add ZeroDivisionError it always returns a zero value as the result. But it's not the accurate result.

Comment: hmm, I have many questions... it's difficult to help you without more context... Can you put more of the surrounding code in your question? (hint: read the editing help to see how to paste nicely formatted code in your question)

Answer (score 0):

Divide by Zero is not limited to any language, this exception occurs at the machine/processor level. When processor detects 'DivideByZero' it throws a DivideByZero exception, whose handlers are already inside the operating system code.

Exception handler provided by user at application level (whether in C++, python or any other high level language) are barely a recovery path for that application should such exception occur.